# CSS: Div won't be centered, and weird size

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `div` and I want center it on the screen with **JQuery**, but it does not work, it's weired because I centered other `divs` with same method.

[image]

**CSS:**

```
#textLinks
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#textLinks').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: ($(window).width()/2 - $('#textLinks').outerWidth()/2),
    top: ($(window).height()/2 + $('#ShapesWrapper').outerHeight()/2)
});
```

**JSFiddle** link: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8tvs8/9/ 
**Actual web page**: http://sosco.ir/index2.html

Comment: I don't think the fiddle link is working. Could you perhaps link to the actual web page this is on?

Comment: You don't put the `<script>` tags in the JavaScript pane in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tvs8/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from your jQuery:

```
$('[id^=text]').css('width', x * 2 + 'px');
$('[id^=text]').css('margin-left', initX + 'px');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8tvs8/11/)**

Or if you want to keep the div narrow, leave in the `$('[id^=text]').css('width', x * 2 + 'px');`

UPDATE: even easier solution seems to be to change this line:

```
$('[id^=text]').css('margin-left', initX + 'px');
```

to this:

```
$('[id^=text]').not('#textLinks').css('margin-left', initX + 'px');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8tvs8/13/)**

Comment: Ah my bad, ID is started by text!

Answer (score 2):

Your div is actually centering correctly..  it just has `margin-left: 87px` in the inline-style.  Remove this, and it will center fine.

You can do this by adding

```
$("#textLinks").css('margin-left','0px');
```

Directly after your `$('[id^=text]').css('margin-left', initX + 'px');` code.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tvs8/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Try repleace:

`$('[id^=text]').css('margin-left', initX + 'px');`

for:

`$('[id^=text]', '#TextWrapper').css('margin-left', initX + 'px');`